# Pass data by link to ruby on rails and undo the change by passing another data by link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As an admin, when I view the users index page, I can 'make' or 'unmake' a user as a resident manager.

When I make a user a residence manager, it works and the link changes to 'unmake...' but when I click to 'unmake...', it doesn't work (the link doesn't change back to 'make')

```
def update                                
    user = User.find(params[:id])                  
    if params[:resident_manager]                 
        user.update(resident_manager: true)         
    else                                                  
        user.update(resident_manager: false)                                                           
    end        

    redirect_to admin_users_path
end

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user != current_user %>
         <p><%= user.email %>                                                                      
         <% if !user.resident_manager? %>                                                           
              <%= link_to "Make Resident Manager", admin_user_path(user, resident_manager: true), method: :put %>
         <% else %>
             <%= link_to "Unmake Resident Manager", admin_user_path(user, resident_manager: false), method: :put %>
           <% end %>                                                                                  
     <% end %> 
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with the answers you guys provided, all of them worked. But I used the toggle because I have a custom validation and 'user.update ...' doesn't work well for it. Using the toggle allows me to call save which automatically checks the user against my custom validation and either proceed or shows the error while rendering the index page.

```
def update                                
    user = User.find(params[:id])                  
    user.toggle :resident_manager if params[:resident_manager]
    user.toggle :resident_assistant if params[:resident_assistant]

    if user.save
        redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
        @users = User.all
        render "index"
    end
end
```

THANKS AGAIN EVERYONE!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by this part of the code

```
if params[:resident_manager]                 
  user.update(resident_manager: true)         
else                                                  
  user.update(resident_manager: false)                                                           
end
```

If you look at the parameters passed to your controller, you'll probably see that `params[:resident_manager]` is always passed.  Change this chunk of code to

```
user.update(resident_manager: params[:resident_manager])
```

And that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that parameters from a form are always strings: an html form doesn't have any type information.

As a result your `if` statement is testing whether the string "true" or the string "false" are truthy. In ruby all objects other than `nil` and `false` are truthy, so in particular all strings are truthy and your code will always set the column in your model to true.

However you can assign that parameter straight to your model, i.e

```
user.update(resident_manager: params[:resident_manager])
```

Because activerecord has typecast code to convert strings into booleans, since this is so common. In particular it will convert '0', 'f' and 'false' to the boolean `false`

Comment: thank you so much, this is very helpful! especially the add explanations... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd be better using the [`toggle`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle) method:

```
def update                                
    user = User.find params[:id]              
    user.toggle :resident_manager if params[:resident_manager] 

    redirect_to admin_users_path
end
```

Considering [boolean values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean) can either be `true` or `false`, the *toggle* functionality will update the `:resident_manager` attribute to the opposite of what it is stored as - achieving the functionality you require

Comment: thank you so much, this is very helpful! never used toggle before... and I'm playing around with it now... Thanks again!